# *** AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'iterator'

Tags: python

I have some code that is returning a list of objects such as

```
[<DomesticHomePage: homepage>, <TopicLandingPage: Advice>, <ArticleListingPage: list two>, <ArticlePage: Article B1>, <ArticlePage: Article B2>, <ArticleListingPage: list one>, <ArticlePage: Article A0>, <ArticlePage: Article A1>, <ArticlePage: Article A2>, <ArticlePage: Article A4>, <ArticlePage: Article C0>, <ArticlePage: Article C1>, <ArticlePage: Article C2>, <ArticlePage: Article C3>, <ArticlePage: Article D1>, <MarketsTopicLandingPage: Markets>, <CountryGuidePage: Test GCP 0>, <CountryGuidePage: Test GCP 1>, <CountryGuidePage: Test GCP 2>, <CountryGuidePage: Test GCP 3>, <CountryGuidePage: Test GCP 4>, <CountryGuidePage: Test GCP 5>, <CountryGuidePage: Test GCP 6>, <CountryGuidePage: Test GCP 7>, <CountryGuidePage: Test GCP 8>,
```

some other part of the code is trying to all the .iterator() method o n on this list with error

*** AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'iterator'

How do I return something that has the iterator method I tried creating an iterator class for the list, but received the error iterator class is not subscript able

to be able to call .iterator() method on the class
created ItemIterator class such as :

```
class ItemsIterator:

    def __init__(self, items):
        self.items = items
        self.count = 0

    def __iter__(self):
        return self
    
    def __next__(self):
        self.count += 1
        return list(self)[self.count]
    
    def __len__(self):
        return len(self.items)
```

Tried adding

```
def __getitem__(self, key):
        return self.items[key]
```

to no avail for subscriptable error

Resolved issue with

```
class ItemsIterator:
    def __init__(self, items):
        self.items = items

    def iterator(self):
        return iter(self.items)

    def __len__(self):
        return len(self.items)
    
    def __getitem__(self, key):
        return ItemsIterator(self.items[key])
```

Comment: `some other part of the code is trying to all the .iterator()`. Is this **your** code, or some library that tries to call that?

Comment: library that I cannot change

Comment: What exactly is the `iterator` method expected to do?

Answer (score 0):

```
class ItemsIterator:
    def __init__(self, items):
        self.items = items
        self.count = 0

    def __iter__(self):
        return self

    def __next__(self):
        if self.count >= len(self.items):
            raise StopIteration
        else:
            self.count += 1
            return self.items[self.count - 1]

    def __len__(self):
        return len(self.items)
```

So, in the `__next__` method, you check if `self.count` exeeds the length of `self.items` to avoid an `IndexError`. If it does, we raise the `StopIteration` exception to signal the end of iteration.

Instead of using `list(self)` inside `__next__` to access the items, you directly index self.items using self.count - 1 to return the current item.

The **len** method returns the length of self.items, which allows you to use the len() function on an instance of ItemsIterator.

Comment: get TypeError: 'ItemsIterator' object is not subscriptable

Answer (score 0):

I solved it myself by fixing `ItemsIterator` to:

```py
class ItemsIterator:
    def __init__(self, items):
        self.items = items

    def iterator(self):
        return iter(self.items)

    def __len__(self):
        return len(self.items)
    
    def __getitem__(self, key):
        return ItemsIterator(self.items[key])
```